# weird behavior in Flex/as3 for-each loop

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

The original code is a bit complex, but it boils down to something like this:

```
for each (var person : Person in someArrayList.toArray())
{
    for each (var friend : Person in person.friendArrayList.toArray())
    {
        trace(person.name + " is friends with " + friend.name);
    }
}
```

There are 3 persons:

1. A is friends with B
2. B is friends with C.

And friendship is **not transitive**. That it, A is not friends with C.

For some reason, what this prints is:

```
A is friends with B
A is friends with C
B is friends with C
```

Now, if I modify the code above to use a temporary variable the printout is correct.

```
for each (var person : Person in someArrayList.toArray())
{
    var friends : Array = person.friendArrayList.toArray(); // temp
    for each (var friend : Person in friends)
    {
        trace(person.name + " is friends with " + friend.name);
    }
}


A is friends with B
B is friends with C
```

Is this by design? Am I losing my mind? What gives?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the code for the Person object (specifically the friendArrayList accessor and the toArray function.

Comment: I'd love to step through a working code sample; can you provide one?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was happening here?

Comment: No, never did find out what the problem was. I don't have the original source code, but iirc it'll recreate with any simple old class that has an ArrayList member variable that refers to other instances.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with oddities like this, there are several ways to detect what's wrong. First one and the fastest would be debugging with a breakpoint before problematic piece of code, and then executing the code step by step.

Second way is to eliminate some of the code, either by creating a new minimized version of the current code, or by commenting some of the code.

Here is what I've tried:
The application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
    >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import weird.Person;
            private function onCreationComplete() : void
            {
                var a : Person = new Person();
                a.name = "A";
                var b : Person = new Person();
                b.name = "B";
                var c : Person = new Person();
                c.name = "C";

                a.friendArrayList.addItem(b);
                b.friendArrayList.addItem(c);

                var someArrayList : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([a,b,c]);

                for each (var person : Person in someArrayList.toArray())
                {
                    for each (var friend : Person in person.friendArrayList.toArray())
                    {
                        trace(person.name + " is friends with " + friend.name);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

And the Person class:

```
package weird
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class Person
    {
        public var name : String = null;
        public var friendArrayList : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

If you run the application you'll see that it executes as expected. Which means you're doing something else in your code that screws up with the iteration in one of the loops.

So if you don't figure out what is broken in your code, it would be interesting (for me at least) to see the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

The `for each..in` statement iterates only through the dynamic properties of an object, not the fixed properties. A fixed property is a property that is defined as part of a class definition. To use the `for each..in` statement with an instance of a user-defined class, you must declare the class with the `dynamic` attribute.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question when he's using the statement with arrays.

Comment: To put it simply, the array he iterates over in the second loop is the property of a user defined class. It's only when he stops iterating over that user defined class property, and iterates over a temp variable that it begins to work correctly. So my answer is absolutely relevant in this case. Whether my answer is correct or not remains to be seen. To test it, add the dynamic attribute to the Person class and see if the desired result is obtained from the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that this is a trimmed down version of the code.

Does the actual code do anything to modify `person.frinedArrayList.toArray()?`

There is a subtle difference in the two versions of your code.

In the latter version where you use the temp variable, the value of `person.friendArrayList.toArray()` is only evaluated once.

However, in the original version, `person.friendArrayList.toArray()` is evaluated at the start of every cycle of the loop.  It's possible that the the return value as it's looping is different, causing the behaviour you're seeing.

For this reason alone, the second version is preferable, as it's more performant.

However, I suspect the real issue lies in the code within the loop, and it's impact on the result of the toArray() call.

Comment: no, the code does not change the array lists. Just prints them out, so to speak.